# Which control does windows live mail use to show the calendar date

Tags: vb.net, controls, calendar, zooming

I would like to create a tabular view of my data in which i would like to show dates as column header and room no as rows header. And room reservation data in that tabular form. I would also like to make date zooming from year, half yearly, month, week to day. Denote the reserved room in some color along with name too.

To my requirement, i found windows live mail's calendar control abit matching without zooming functionality.

Here is a sample of windows live mail's control:
http://www.flickr.com/photos/30150279@N06/5444844190/

I would like to get reference/example of control/project matching my requirement.

Comment: This is almost certainly a custom control or collection of controls and is unlikely to be publicly available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The control used by Windows Live is probably something custom built.  There are tons of examples of controls that do something similar out on code project.  Here are a few:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/docview/WinFormsCalendarView.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFOutlookCalendar.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/selection/Calendardayview.aspx